# Installed Java EE SDK 7 but NetBeans 8.0 will only create Java EE 6 Web app

Tags: macos, netbeans, java-ee-7

I am using Mac OS X and I have Java EE SDK 7 installed, but when I try to create a new web application via NetBeans 8.0 it only gives me two options for the Java EE Version: 'Java EE 5' or 'Java EE 6 Web'.  Is it possible to use Java EE 7 for my web app?

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled all Java versions, GlassFish versions, and Tomcat.  Then I reinstalled the latest Java EE 7 bundled with GlassFish 4 and my problem was solved!